# Count all subsets with given sum - Java

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset, subset-sum, coin-change

I have an array `list` of distinct positive integers representing a set `L`, and an integer `S`. What's the fastest way to count all subsets of `L` which have the sum of their elements equal to `S`, instead of iterating over all subsets and just checking if each subset's sum equal is equal to `S`?

Comment: if you don't have restriction on the `S` you can't do better than brute force - it's a NP problem, else you could do it in `O(n * S)`

Comment: Hi @svs. what do you mean by a restriction on the `sum`? In this case I know that `S <= 5000`.

Comment: @RahulNori there is a difference. In `Coin Change Algorithm` you can repeat elements whereas here you can't.

Comment: @svs i stand corrected. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: by `sum` I meant `S`. the question is do you need to find all the subsets explicitly or just their count?

Comment: @svs I don't need the subsets fully explicitly, but with `f` being another function I need to count all subsets such that the minimum of `f` over that subset is large enough.

Comment: could you update your question by specifying exactly what you said + giving some example?

Comment: I'll do so later - I don't have access to my computer right now, being on my phone.

Comment: More importantly, on second thought I actually only need the number of such subsets.

Comment: @LiamBaker, yes, please update the question. If all you need in the number of such subsets, then a very easy dynamic programming solution (similar to knapsack problem) would do. A common approach is to calculate only the yes/no answer (there there is at least one such subset), but it is easy to modify to find the total number of such subsets.

Comment: @LiamBaker ...and if you need to iterate over all of them, then it can be done in O(K) given you have the DP matrix, with K being the number of such subsets, but that's still non-polynomial as K may be very large. And obviously you can not do better.

Comment: @LiamBaker, see http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Coin_Change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved in `O(NS)` using a simple dynamic programming approach, similar to knapsack problem. Let's for each `Q` and for each `i` solve the following problem: how many subsets of first `i` elements of `L` exist so that their sum is equal to `Q`. Let us denote the number of such subsets `C[i,Q]`.

Obviously, `C[0,0]=1` and `C[0,Q]=0` for `Q!=0`. (Note that `i=0` denotes first 0 elements, that is no elements.)

For a bigger `i` we have two possibilities: either the last available element (`L[i-1]`) is taken to our set, then we have `C[i-1, Q-L[i-1]]` such sets. Either it is not taken, then we have `C[i-1, Q]` such sets. Therefore, `C[i,Q]=C[i-1, Q-L[i-1]]+C[i-1, Q]`. Iterating over `i` and `Q`, we calculate all `C`s.

Note that if all elements in `L` are non-negative, then you can solve the problem only for non-negative `Q`s, and the first term disappears if `Q<L[i-1]`. If negative elements are allowed, then you need to consider negative `Q`s too.

Comment: there is a difference with the question asked. In Coin Change Algorithm you can repeat elements whereas here you can't

Comment: @svs there can be versions of different coin change problem. My algorithm described in answer allows each element only once.

Comment: @svs, though the link was indeed for a problem with infinite coins. Thus removed the link.